# Firebase Upload images | make use of NSProgress

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, nsprogress

I have to upload 3 Images to Firebase. I'd like to monitor the upload progress of all three images via [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress).

```
let currentUploadTask:StorageUploadTask = uploadPath.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (storageMetaData, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    //TODO: Error handling
                }else{
                    print("Upload Finished")
                }
            }
```

You get to the NSProgress object via `currentUploadTask.snapshot.progress`
And in fact you get the progress percentage if you run `currentUploadTask.snapshot.progress.fractionCompleted`

Once I combine all "Firebase progresses" to one big progress things fall apart.

```
let progress:Progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 3)
progress.addChild(currentUploadTask.snapshot.progress!, withPendingUnitCount: currentUploadTask.snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)

// Observe progress.fractionCompleted ----> always 0.0
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What you're doing here is a little unclear. An observer needs to be added to the uploadTask to monitor it. From the snapshot that's passed in, you can get the percentage complete (and other data) for that task. `let complete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
/ Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)`. If you want to combine all of the uploads into one, you would need to combine the three total unit counts together and the completed counts and then divide. See [Monitor Upload Progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do -- I wanted to do it too: you want to use the `NSProgress` object itself and simply add it as a child of a top-level `NSProgress` object.

Unfortunately I can see from `FirebaseStorage` code that this isn't possible:

```
- (FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *)snapshot {
  @synchronized(self) {
    NSProgress *progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:self.progress.totalUnitCount];
```

... because a new `NSProgress` object is made every time, rather than re-using the existing one. I'll file a feature improvement over on github about it.